# DataTemplate of Grid inside ListView is not resizing

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have a `ListView` that lays on top of UI graphics in my `UserControl` that I want to show and size using a `Grid` that matches the parent grid.  I'm trying to template the way each item shown and sized using the `ListView.ItemTemplate`.  The issue I'm having is that the `DataTemplate` is not sizing to the main `Grid` of the UI, and I'm not sure why.

This is what I've done, I think it a fairly simple and straight forward datatemplate:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusFilter}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="12">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="92"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ECNNumber}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=DateECNDue}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Model.Model}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <--More stuff for each column-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When this is displayed the grid is completely bypassed and each element is shown like a horizontally aligned stackpanel.  To test that my `DataTemplate` wasn't faulty I threw it into an `ItemsControl` and it worked perfectly.  It resized with the parent grid without any issues.

Why isn't this working for the `ListView`, and how do I get it to work?  I need the selection and scrollview capability of the `ListView` otherwise I'd be using the `ItemsControl`.

I read something about `Grid.SharedSizeScope` but that doesn't work with dynamic sizing of grid, and that's all I could really find on this issue.

Comment: Where is the code of the main Grid? You need to provide us enough information/code for us to replicate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to check which style the ListBox is using? Maybe try adding Style="{x:Null}" just to be sure.

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira, thanks for the response.  The listview is inside a Grid of the exact same set up as the datatemplate, but that isn't the issue or the question.  Given the information that i've posted, the problem can be replicated.  The grid in the datatemplate in the listview does not dynamically resize like you would think it would using the "*" in the columndefinitions.  But it works if you add the exact same datatemplate inside an itemscontrol.

Comment: @GuidoC thanks for the comment.  There isn't a style applied to the listview and changing it to null doesn't change the outcome of the grid resizing.